# Why does my mouse take longer to respond

Tags: mouse

I have been searching hard, but couldn't find anyone with similar situation. I will try to explain it.
So far I've been using a 16 inch HD monitor with $20 mouse. Everything is okay.
Then I switched to full HD 32 inch TV with another $20 mouse (Redragon Centrophorus). Now there is some stutter, but it is dependant on distance travelled by the mouse. I move the mouse very very slowly, for example - 0.1 mm, the cursor doesnt't move. I move it 0.1 mm more and then it moves on the screen by 0.2 mm. Like it is not dependant on input time or something, but rather it has a minimum distance for registering a movement.

Comment: What OS are you running? The reason this is happening, is because the mouse has no mouse accelleration. Different OSses have different places where mouse accelleration or similar can be turned on.

Comment: What screen resolution are you using?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. I turned off mouse acceleration from the mouse settings. The resolution I am on is 1920x1080, 32 inch

Comment: You need to turn on mouse acceleration or lower the mouse movement speed. What you describe is normal for mousing.